# Copying folder not working anymore in Singularity 3

Tags: singularity-container

I have a Singularity recipe in which I want to copy some folders inside the container, written like

```
%files
    backend/
```

This worked just fine in the past.
But recently I upgraded from Singularity 2 to Singularity 3, and now trying to build this starts with giving me the warning

```
WARNING: backend/ : [backend/]
```

and nothing is copied.

Do I need to adjust my syntax?

Edit: I tried to do the same with a single file, doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out. The syntax changed. The correct new syntax is:

```
%files
    backend/* backend/
```

Apparently, it won't simply copy folders anymore and instead you have to use the wild card. As those are files, the target folder has to be provided.
The warning message still persists, though.

Comment: Be careful, though: you have to explicitly give a destination path! When using `backend/*` without specifying a destination folder, the files were copied into a folder `backend/*/` in my case. Using `backend/ backend/` without `*` also worked fine for me btw.